# log into ColdFusion site from JS-based AIR app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion, air

I have the following ColdFusion code on a server (which I'm not able to change) :

```
<cfquery name="getlogin" datasource="#application.dsn#">
        SELECT * 
        FROM tbl_userAccount
        WHERE userName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.userName#"/> AND passWord = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.passWord#"/> AND siteID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#application.siteID#"/>
    </cfquery>
```

and I'm trying to build a JavaScript window for logging into it from an Adobe AIR app.

Specifically, I want it to send the user credentials (uName and pWord), and bring back the account ID (which would also be included in the 'SELECT *' statement).

Can anyone help me get started with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really quick dirty way to get started with this to drop that query into a method in a CFC.

That method would take two parameters for username and password. Replace the form variables in the cfqueryparms with the appropriate arguments on your method.

On the method you should set the return type as numeric and the returnttype as json.
You'll be able to call the method in the CFC from an Ajax post accepting back the account id. Basically just use the CFC as a webservice.

Things you'll need to do are validating the username and password, returning zero or a negative number if you don't get a single record returned by your query, take the * out of the select and only return the account id.

Comment: Is there no way to script around it so as to avoid turning that into a CFC? Right now, the site this is accessing has everything in CFM pages, and I don't want to put the lead dev through the hassles of turning things into CFCs if there's any way to avoid it...

Comment: You can probably do a http post via javascript to the form action page, but you're going to have to scrape the html response to try and find the account id if its even present in the page. You're opening yourself up to a world of pain to be quite honest.

Comment: OK, thanks; I appreciate your help - I'll see if I can get some of these CFMs turned into CFCs.